# xlrd - Search Excel column for value and return row id

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have multiple spreadsheets with x,y plot data. I want to search the first column in each spreadsheet for a specific number value, and then get the row id of that value so I can print all the values in that row.

This is what I have so far, but it's not working. I'm having trouble with the part that searches for the specific value in first column. The value I'm looking for in the first column is 2.2000229358673.

```
import os, sys
import xlrd

work_dir = os.getcwd()
excelfile_list = [x for x in os.listdir(work_dir) if x.split('.')[-1].lower() == 'xlsx']

for xfile in excelfile_list:
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(work_dir + '\\' + xfile)
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    from xlrd.sheet import ctype_text
    cellid = worksheet.cell(0,0)
    print('%s' % (cellid.value))

    rowidx = worksheet.col_values(0).index(2.2000229358673)

    rowid = worksheet.row(rowidx)

    for idx, cell_obj in enumerate(rowid):
        cell_type_str = ctype_text.get(cell_obj.ctype, 'unknown type')
        print('%s' % (cell_obj.value))
```